# Can anyone edit the jquery localscroll plugin to give it a onAfter callback aswell as onBefore?

Tags: jquery-plugins

The localscroll jquery plugin has an onBefore option which allows you to specify a function to execute before the animation but it doesn't have one for after the animation. The plugin looks pretty simple and I'm sure it would be a 5 minute job for someone who knows what theyre doing but I dont!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its ok you can actually put onAfter it just wasnt documented but the functionality is there